# Knives that never need to be sharpened

Tags: steel, metallurgy

I have a set of kitchen knives which I've owned for 18 years. These knives were sold as "never need sharpening". I assumed that to be complete nonsense at the time BUT it has proved to be true! These knives have never once been sharpened in 18 years and are used every day.

How is this possible - and given that it is possible, why are most knives still made to be sharpened regularly? They were not at all expensive so that can't be the reason.

[image]

EDIT: I've just found the claim from the original packaging: "These Fusion Infinity knives are fused with tungsten carbide giving them an extremely hard edge. There is no need to sharpen these knives."

So, the question becomes resolves down to "Why doesn't everyone do this?" None of the answers have tried to address this angle yet.

Comment: hard material on the cutting edge, they probably dulled a bit though.

Comment: @ratchetfreak You may well be right, the edge is certainly quite unusual. I will post a photo later. What material do you think it might be? It could well be that the edge has dulled in 18 years, but they are all still more than adequate for day to day use.

Comment: It's possible that they are "sharp" in that they cut things decently well.  However, I'm a firm believer that a knife can never be sharp enough.  The sharper the edge, the easier (and safer) it is to cut things.  Your knives could probably still use some honing to bring them to a razor edge.

As a quick question, do they pass the [paper test](http://lifehacker.com/5896693/use-a-sheet-of-paper-to-make-sure-your-knife-is-as-sharp-as-it-should-be)?  Do they cut tomatoes without crushing them?  I wouldn't consider a kitchen knife sharp if it can't do both of those tasks.

Comment: Are you sure the knives are made of steel? Ceramic knives are famed for keeping their edge, since they are made of (I believe) one of the hardest materials (up there with diamonds).

Comment: @Wasabi Yes, they're steel, see the new photo for proof!

Comment: @grfrazee OK, so they don't pass the "paper test" but they do cut tomatoes with no problem. I have no doubt that a chef would find them unacceptably blunt - but they are certainly much sharper than any other knife I've used over a month since it was last sharpened.

Comment: You still have the original packaging from 18 years ago? I find that more astounding than that it is still sharp :P

Comment: @Steve I keep all instruction books in binders and they only get thrown away when the item gets thrown away (usually a couple of years after!) This one has been migrated to the back of a binder but never thrown away because we still have the knives!

Comment: This question is about the food service and home goods industries. There is no engineering involved in determining whether a knife is sharp enough to prepare food or why people choose harder or softer knives in the kitchen. I recommend browsing the [sharpening](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharpening) and [knives](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knives) tags on Seasoned Advice. There is an incredible amount of information online already about hard edges vs. soft edges - and much of it is a matter of personal preference, even among chefs.

Comment: @Air I've asked for it to be closed but it's not been done yet.

Answer (score 4):

I've found a couple things about these knives (and "stay-sharp" knives in general).

First, the knives you have appear to be treated with tungsten carbide on the edges per [this website](http://www.dotmaison.com/fusionknives_p_55821.html) and [this one](http://www.britishblades.com/forums/showthread.php?138996-Richardson-Sheffield-Fusion-Knives-Sharpening).  Since TC is incredibly hard, it dulls very slowly, hence why it is used for heavy-duty metal cutting operations.

Second, the edge of the blade probably has micro-serrations that act like a tiny saw, effectively sawing through the cut material when you drag the knife through it (see [here](http://www.bladeforums.com/forums/showthread.php/196014-quot-Never-Sharpen-quot-kitchen-knives)).  Realistically, this is what happens with a "properly" sharpened knife anyway at the microscopic level, though the serrations you'll find on a "stay-sharp" knife are relatively much larger.

I should also note that is it possible to sharpen those knives you have, but you'll probably need something like a diamond plate to do so.

In regards to your edited question: the tungsten carbide edge, though durable, will eventually dull and it is a pain to properly sharpen again. Chefs will send their knives out for professional sharpening every so often, and I would imagine a service would charge extra for doing TC (this is a guess).  Otherwise, between sharpenings, a chef will want to just swipe his knives on a honing steel a few times between uses to touch the edge up (this is not actually sharpening, but is merely straightening out the burr on the edge).  The honing steel a chef uses is harder than the knife blade, so it is able to straighten the burr without being damaged.  With TC, since it is harder than the honing steel, it would scratch and gouge a honing steel and have no effect on the knife's edge.

Comment: gfrazee As you can see from the photo, the brand is "Fusion", the same as the first link you have given. In fact, I've just remembered that I still have the original "Instructions", see the edit in the question.

Comment: Yes, I know.  I found the information in my Answer by searching the knife name based on your picture :-)

Comment: Apologies. Your other link is interesting too - people's experience seems to be different to mine - unless they assumed they needed to sharpen them and actually damaged the edge.

Comment: That's possible, or they also could have used them much, much more than you have or abused them.  Anyway, does this answer your question?

Comment: I'm not exaggerating when I say they are used every day. The only confounding factor I suppose I need to add is that we only ever use Nylon chopping boards - I know a lot of people like the glass ones  and the instructions do specifically state not to use ceramic or glass chopping boards.

Comment: If you value your cutting edges, NEVER use a glass or ceramic cutting board.

Comment: Have you ever worked in a professional kitchen? Many pros send out their knives regularly to a sharpening service, monthly or even weekly, depending on the type of knife, how many they have in rotation, how much use they get, etc. There is no such thing as a steel that sharpens knives, despite the fact that people insist on mislabeling honing steels as "sharpening" steels. A steel, used properly in conjunction with sharpening, can maintain a good edge but it does not under any circumstance create an edge.

Comment: @Air Admittedly I have not.  You bring up a good point - I sharpen my knives myself, so I didn't think about that.  And yes, the steel doesn't sharpen the knife as much as it hones the edge, so I have edited my Answer to be more explicit on that front.  Thank you for pointing out that my post was not descriptive enough.

Answer (score 2):

One possible explanation to your observation is that these knives come in a special holder, which contains a sharpener at each position you can insert a knife.  Each knife is sharpened a little when it is removed or replaced in the holder.  The advertising claim only meant that you won't have to deliberately sharpen them.

I have a set of knives like this, and this method works very well.  You can feel the grinding action when you remove or insert a knife into the holder.

Comment: No, I know what you mean because I owned one of those knives many years ago and it did work very well and I can see why you might think that. These are 6 knives in an ordinary wooden knife block.